# How do I emulate the clicking of a NavigationLink on textFieldShouldReturn?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have this NavigationLink in a List in my main ContentView:

```
List(searchModel.suggestedQueries, id: \.self) { suggestedQuery in
    NavigationLink(destination: ResultView(query: suggestedQuery)) {
        Text(suggestedQuery)
    }
}
```

This works great, but this list contains some query suggestions based on what they have typed in a UIViewRepresentable UITextField:

```
struct SearchTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
        
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            let text = textField.text ?? ""
            
            if (text != "") {
                // go to search results
            }
            
            return false
        }
    }

    ...
```

In the textFieldShouldReturn method, I want to perform an action as if they are clicking a NavigationLink with the same destination.

I'm looking for something like this, but I don't know how to do it properly:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let text = textField.text ?? ""
    
    if (text != "") {
        emulateNavigationLink(destination: ResultView(query: text))
    }
    
    return false
}
```

How do I do this? I've read up on `isActive` but was confused with how to use it with parameters etc.

Comment: It is not clear which exactly navigation link from List should be activated on SearchTextField change, or how they relates. Would you elaborate more on this?

Comment: `searchModel` contains a Published property called `query` and it has a `didSet` function which updates the `suggestedQueries` when it changes. The SearchTextField has this `query` property binded to it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using a NavigationLink with an empty view, and binded a boolean to the TextField for `isActive`.